# Selenium chromedriver with headless mode fails to start when executed from SSH

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, centos7, xvfb

I have looked for similar questions, but couldn't find any.

I'm trying to run chrome browser in headless mode (with Selenium) on a CentOS 7 platform. The site works with SSL (I had to download and install the certificate locally on the machine that runs the Chrome client, so it can confirm it. Before that, I had gotten 'SSL certificate' issues)

When I'm running my script with **GUI** environment (KDE), everything works. Also in **headless** mode.

However, if I connect to the machine through SSH and execute the same script - the driver fails to 'open' chrome, load pages, no elements present, etc.

This is the code snippet:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import os
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = '/opt/google/chrome/chrome'
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1024,768')
os.environ['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = driver_path

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=chrome_options,
                          service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'])
```

I suspect it relates somehow to **Xvfb** (which is started by pyvirtualdisplay). I've also checked if there are environment variables different between the two scenarios, but couldn't put a finger on the missing piece.

I've checked the difference in the chromedriver log between the two scenarios (running from SSH compared to running using GUI),
and I get this error printed:

```
ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(922)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for mysite failed err=-8179
```

I'm not sure this is related, it might be something else, because I have trust from this client to this webserver (SSL info is Secure).

Any suggestions are welcome. I'm trying to solve this issue for couple days now.

Comment: Did you find solution to this problem?